# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'xxx'

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

Entity class 1

```
       @Entity
       @Table(name = "TICKETS")
       public class Ticket {

       ....

      @Column(name = "MERCHANT_NBR")
      private String merchant_nbr;

      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_nbr", nullable = false)
      private Merchant merchant;

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name ="merchantNBR", nullable = false)
     private merchantDetails merchantDetails;
```

Entity class 2

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="MERCHANT_DETAILS")
  public class merchantDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name="MERCHANT_NBR")
    private String merchantNBR;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Ticket> ticket;
```

error its giving...invalid column 'merchantNBR'.But I have a column by that name.

```
   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'merchantNBR'.
```

Comment: the column name is MERCHANT_NBR and not merchantNBR as it's showed in your hibernate annotation

Comment: thanks for your reply. When I change that, it gives this:
"Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.triton.model.Ticket column: merchant_nbr" . does not hibernate allow mapping to two different table from one column?

Comment: are you using that column for join the two entities

Comment: Yes. 'MERCHANT_NBR' is used to connect both merchantDetails(merchantNBR) and Ticket(merchant_nbr).Also Ticket is connected with Merchant table with the same column.

Answer (score 1):

so it's a join column not a column and for that you have to use the proper annotation for joining two entities which is `@JoinColumn` 
see this it may be helpful

```
@joinColumn(name = "MERCHANT_NBR" ,referencedColumnName="merchantNBR")
      private String merchant_nbr;
```

here i supposed that you've changed the column name in entitie class 2 from

```
@Column(name="MERCHANT_NBR") to `@Column(name="merchantNBR")`
```

Comment: I did that change. But it still giving me the error of 'repeated column in mapping for entity for Ticket column merchant_nbr...'

Comment: are you sure that they have a different name ??

Comment: Let me change the names and check once more if I am making any mistakes in the column names..which I think is the case. Thanks for the replies !